# Pandas : Find the column name which has the minimum/maximum value of a single row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

in a dataframe using Pandas, I'd like to know how to find a column name which has the minimum or maximum value for a given row, not all the rows.
I've been searching for answers and i kept reaching the following answer : df.idxmin(axis=1)
This gives all the minimum values for each rows, but I am only seeking the comumn for one specific row. Thanks for your help !

Comment: `df.iloc[0].idxmin()` for just the first row

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'store_1': [10, 20, 40], 
        'store_2': [50, 70,80], 
        'store_3': [5000, 20,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

#### My FOO data for example::

|  | store_1 | store_2 | store_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 50 | 5000 |
| 1 | 20 | 70 | 20 |
| 2 | 40 | 80 | 10 |

#### To find on dataframe the column name with `min` value

```
df.iloc[0].idxmin()
```

> 'store_1'

#### To find on dataframe the columns with `max` value

```
df.iloc[0].idxmax()
```

> 'store_3'

#### Find the `min` value from `store_1` col:

```
df.store_1.min()
```

> 10

#### Find the `max` value from `store_1` col:

```
df.store_1.max()
```

> 40

#### Find the `min` value from `store_2` col:

df.store_2.min()

> 50

#### Find the `max`value from `store_2` col:

```
df.store_2.max()
```

> 80

#### Find the `min` value from `store_3` col:

```
df.store_3.min()
```

> 10

#### Find the `max` value from `store_3` col:

```
df.store_3.max()
```

> 5000

Just remember that the syntax `df.store_1` is the same of `df['store_1']`  ...

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
df.max().argmax()
```

provides the column index in which the largest element resides (or the first column index of the largest elements, when the column index is non-unique).

In turn,

```
df.iloc[i].argmax()
```

provides the index for the row with index `i`.